# What mechanisms exist for the excision of specific sequences from DNA?

Tags: dna, recombination

I already know about recombinases (specifically excisionases), but was wondering if there were other mechanisms present.

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need additional assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: The absolute standard way has to be PCR. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerase_chain_reaction

Design primers for each end of a known sequence, provide DNA containing that sequence, and (hey presto!) amplify the length between the primers.

Comment: If you're asking about how sequences are excised in nature, an interesting case is the CRISPR-Cas viral defence system of bacteria, where sequences adjacent to a particular "handle" or "signal" in the viral genome are excised and added to an array in the bacterial genome which acts as a memory for immunity. I don't know how the mechanism works!

Comment: What about endonucleases?

Comment: I know about the Cas9 mechanism as well.  I guess my question was more oriented towards the "cutting out" of a sequence of DNA and then a religation of the two flanking ends.  Cas9 does the first part, but not the second part, while recombinases do both.

Answer (score 1):

Genome editing techniques like CRISPR-Cas and TALEN use non-specific recombinases coupled to a DNA-recognizing part that can be designed to be specific for any stretch of sequence, as it is constructed out of single zinc-finger 'modules' that each specifically bind a couple of nucleotides (one nucleotide each in the case of TALEN).